# How to Combine Univariate GARCH Models?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, garch

We fitted univariate GARCH models to several time series. We would like to make sure that the forecasts also consider the correlation structure between the time series.

The literature presents some multivariate GARCH models which can be directly fitted to multivariate time series. However, we would prefer to combine the univariate GARCH models by somewhat imposing the correlations on top of the forecasts.

Do you have some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Two good reviews of multivariate GARCH models are Bauwens et al. ["Multivariate GARCH models: A survey"](http://www.city.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0004/78952/BauwensLaurentRomboutsJAE2006.pdf) (2006) and Silvennoinen & Teräsvirta ["Multivariate GARCH models"](http://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/56218/1/538862637.pdf) 2009.

Comment: Thanks, @RichardHardy. I had found Bauwens but I think it is a bit too theoretical. I'll have a look at Silvennoinen. Thanks again.

Comment: Personally, I found Bauwens et al. easier than S. & T., but it was a while ago, so I don't really remember well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

1. Fit a correlation matrix to the standardized residuals. GARCH gives you time-varying volatility, so divide the input to the GARCH model by the time-varying standard deviation. This gives standardized residuals that you can fit a correlation matrix to.
2. Use a copula. This approach is similar to the above, but provides a little bit more freedom. For instance, you could more easily handle GARCH models with $t$ distributions.
3. Model the time-varying correlation. There are multivariate versions of GARCH, e.g. DCC GARCH, that could handle the univariate and multivariate time-varying volatility jointly.

Comment: Very solid answer. Thanks @John. I think the 2. approach will be followed.